# How to match relationships pattern using boolean constraints in Neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

My goal is to navigate from START to END and I also want to walk along the ENTER/EXIT combination paths.

In this simple case I have to write:

```
(START)-[:FLOWS_TO]->()-[:ENTER]->......->[:EXIT]->()-[:FLOWS_FROM]->()-[:FLOWS_TO]->(END)
```

Now imagine that I want to define a more general query like `(START)-[r*1..n]->(END)` with the ability to express something like this:

```
FROM START MATCH (FLOWS_TO*1..n OR (ENTER -> FLOWS_TO*1..n -> EXIT -> FLOWS_FROM))*1..n TO END
```

so basically evaluating a boolean string and allowing "r" to become one (or more) of these matching alternatives. How to do so?

[image]

Comment: Do you need both `FLOWS_FROM` and `FLOWS_TO`? Why not keep only one and flip the direction if needed?

Comment: Hi @fbiville and thanks for the comment. Actually yes, I need both the labels because in my case the sequence `FLOWS_TO -> FLOWS_FROM` is an impossible path and I need to force neo4j to pass through the subgraph `ENTER-> .... ->EXIT`. Neither I can change or swap relationships from a node to another. I need the relationship `r` to become  `FLOWS_TO*1..n` or the sequence `ENTRY AND FLOWS_TO*1..n AND EXIT AND FLOWS_FROM`...this is the reason why I need something like a boolean evaluator. I hope I explained my problem

Comment: Could you share a sample data set?